# Diferença na formatação do conteúdo na TextArea e bloco de notas

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC onde exibo em uma área de texto um conteúdo que está no banco de dados.

```
@Html.TextArea("Avisos", Model.Avisos, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 50, style = "max-width:none", @readonly = "" })
```

A exibição fica desalinhada assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém se eu copiar o conteúdo da área de texto, e colar no bloco de notas, fica ok, como esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho a mínima ideia do porque da diferença e de como resolver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por causa da fonte usada dentro de `<textarea>`. Possivelmente a folha de estilo não está usando uma fonte monoespaçada.

Experimente definir um estilo assim:

```
textarea {
  font-family: Consolas, Lucida Console, Courier New, Courier;
}
```

No seu caso, pode-se definir *inline*, assim:

```
@Html.TextArea("Avisos", Model.Avisos, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 50, style = "max-width: none; font-family: Consolas, Lucida Console, Courier New, Courier", @readonly = "" })
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3s82xej/).

Comment: Deu certo valeu! Eu tenho esse mesmo problema numa aplicação Silverlight. vou tentar resolver lá mudando a fonte também.